# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException in Java

Tags: java

```
if(locs!=null)
{
    System.out.println("location are not null");
    Iterator ite = locs.iterator();
    DefaultComboItem locObj = null;
    ArrayList locCode = null;
    String cod=null;
    String name=null;
    while(ite.hasNext())
    {
        locCode = (ArrayList) ite.next();
        Iterator iter = locCode.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext())
        {
            cod=(String)iter.next();
            System.out.println("Code="+cod);
            name=(String)iter.next();
            System.out.println("name="+name);
            locObj = new DefaultComboItem(cod, name);
            colRet.add(locObj);
        }
    }

}
```

on executing above code i am getting "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"
getting this exception on 
 cod=(String)iter.next();
line, because iter.next(); returns bigDecimal value and i am converting into String variable

Please help me

Comment: No ideas where? No stack trace or line number or anything?

Comment: Probably a good example on how not to ask a question. 
Can you provide context? Which libraries are you using, which line did the exception occurred on, stack trace?

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `next()` twice, but only checking `hasNext()` once in the while loop condition. If your list has an odd number of elements, this code will throw a `NoSuchElementException`, which may be getting wrapped in an `InvocationTargetException` somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You can't cast a BigDecimal directly to String. Try iter.next().toString() instead.

Also it would be a good idea to use generics on the Iterators since it makes it clearer what they return (and you can access the specific methods of that class directly (no cast needed)).